# Laravel: Map by key and get result in json

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using mailgun API and batch sending , in order to properly send batch mails with recipent variables I must provide a valid JSON-encoded dictionary, where key is a plain recipient address and value is a dictionary with variables.

The JSON object I wanna obtain is as follows:

```
'{ "bob@example.com": {"username":"Bob", "id":1} ,
 { "pete@example.com": {"first":"Pete", "id":2} ,'
```

This is what I have so far (pseudocode):

```
$subs = Sub::all();

        foreach($subs as $sub)
        {
            $username = mailName($email->email);
            $id = $sub->id;
        }
```

How could I do this, is it possible to do with laravel collection methods?

Thanks in advance and sorry for noob question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use collection to get the result, so back to your pseudocode, you can achieve it as this:

```
$data = collect();

foreach($subs as $sub)
{
    $data[$email->email] = [
      'username' => mailName($email->email),
      'id' => $sub->id
    ];
}

$data->toJson(); // this line will give you the expected result
```